# Reading from .properties file in Ant build.xml

Tags: java, ant

I need some help with using Ant's property files. I have the following:

1. A *build.properties* file. This file contains one piece of
   information: `on=1`
2. An ant.xml file. This file contains my build instructions.

I want to read the `on` attribute from my properties file and if the value is `1` I want to execute a task in my build file. Otherwise I want it to do nothing. Can anyone guide me on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean, you want to do something? im assuming something with ant.xml?

Answer (score 25):

This should be all you need to do:

1.Grab the latest version of [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) JAR and place in lib
   folder of your Ant installation.

2.Include your properties in your build script

```
<property file="build.properties"/>
```

3.Add the following taskdef entry to your build script

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
```

4.And then finally, define an if task like so:

```
<if>
 <equals arg1="${on}" arg2="1" />
 <then>
   <echo message="I am going to do something here" />
 </then>
 <else>
   <echo message="I am going to do nothing" />
 </else>
</if>
```

Note that you can prepend an identifier to properties you import from property files. So for example you could do your import like so:

```
<property file="build.properties" prefix="uniqueprefix"/>
```

And then you would reference in your file, 'uniqueprefix.on', instead of just 'on'.

```
<equals arg1="${uniqueprefix.on}" arg2="1" />
```

You can use the built-in conditional task from Ant, but I have a feeling that if you need it you are better off with the extra functions that ant-contrib brings to the table. Also, note that its standard to name your build file as '*build.xml*', and not '*ant.xml*'. As it is, Ant will not be able to automatically locate it, given the name you have used. Good luck.

Comment: +1 and I'd accept it, although - with this solution we have to be careful an should choose an special namespace for those external properties - otherwise we might overwrite existing properties accidently. Just imagine, property `on` was defined in `build.xml` too...

Comment: @Andreas_D, its actually possible to append a unique identifier to all properties included via property file. I will update my answer to include this information.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to write your own Ant Task or use other libs, just "clean" ant, have a look at this one:

mybuild.properties:

```
on=on
```

Use on or true or something like that, 1 will not work.

build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="project" default="default">
    <property file="mybuild.properties"/>    

    <target name="default" depends="on, off" description="description">
        <echo>default</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="on" if="${on}">
      <echo>on</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="off" unless="${on}">
      <echo>off</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: thank you all :)) it`s working. I`m going forward with my project! :*

Answer (score 4):

Seems to me that you want to implement something like below given task.

```
<property file="build.properties" />



<target name="default" description="Homeworks">
    <condition property="on">
        <equals arg1="{on}" arg2="1" />
    </condition>
    <antcall target="taska" />
    <antcall target="taskb" />
</target>

<target name="taska" if="on">
    <echo message="Testing task one" />
</target>
<target name="taskb" unless="on">
    <echo message="Testing task two" />
</target>
```

Let me know if you want a explanation, in details.

Comment: thx very much. But i have still problem. value "on" ​​from a properties in general is not taken into consideration. if I change "on" to "off" ant call taskb, but if I assign to "on" any number- taska always run.

Answer (score 0):

An approach, that looks difficult but is, in fact, pretty easy: write a custom ant task (one simple java class, <20 lines of code). The task will

1. read the properties file (location/name can be passed as an attribute to the task)
2. assign the value of `on` to an ant property

Then you can use that ant property for your flow control.

```
public class MyOwnTask extends Task {

  private String filename = "build.properties"; // some default value

  public void setFilename(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
  }

  public void execute() {   // the "main" method
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(filename);
    String onValue = p.get("on");
    getProject().setProperty("ON_PROPERTY", onValue);
  }
}
```

Then you need some `<taskdef>` and that's it.

Comment: Why would you need to do this when you can import a properties file in an Ant script?

Comment: @Perception - why don't you make an answer from this valuable information? Custom ant tasks is definitely more fun :)

Comment: Even more fun is writing your own build harness for Ant, utilizing its Java API. I've submitted an answer, as humbly requested :-)